# Problems when downloading file from server

Tags: php, html, download

When trying to download a `.txt` file from my server, it's downloading the page which is showing right now. I want it to echo text on the page and then after download, a txt which is uploaded to the server.

Code:

```
createfile($secretkey, $botkey);
downloadfile($secretkey);
echo "<h1>Thank you for buying EX-7!</h1></br>";
```

Function createfile

```
$myfile = fopen($secretkey. ".txt", "w");
$txt = "Thank you for buying EX-7! We have whitelisted you for EX-7, Congratulations!";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Function downloadfile:

```
$filename = $secretkey. '.txt';
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($filename);
```

It is downloading a file, but the file's text is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Thank you for purchasing! </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="middlediv">

    <div class="text">
        <h1>Thank you for buying EX-7!</h1>
```

Comment: How do you mean none resolved. They are all resolved?

Comment: I'm sorry i didnt know i had to accept the solution.

Comment: You've just put a smile on quite a few people's faces :-) *cheers*

Comment: your given code does not have any issue. that code is working fine

Comment: Why would i ask a question here if it was working fine?

Comment: It does not download the file from the server. it is downloading the page that it was supposed to echo